# How do I find the broken part of WordPress code in the custom function.php (contains a lot of internal files)?

Tags: wordpress

My site displays the following error and the problem is that I don't know exactly which line and which file in my **function.php** set has a problem!

I have set the following code to true in the **wp-config.php** file
**define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );**

```
Notice: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in /home/aluper/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5360

Notice: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in /home/aluper/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 33
```

Let me explain further, my **function.php** file contains several other php files that are called inside function.php (**and my function.php file itself is finally 100 lines of code**) and when I receive the above error code, how should I know which one of the (imported) files inside my **function.php** and which line of that file has a problem?!

I know that the codes of all the files can be re-inserted into the **function.php** file, but I think there should be a more rational and simple method.

For example, my function.php file is as follows:

```
require_once('template-parts/1.php');
require_once('template-parts/2.php');
require_once('template-parts/3.php');
require_once('template-parts/4.php');
require_once('template-parts/5.php');
require_once('template-parts/6.php');
require_once('template-parts/7.php');
require_once('template-parts/8.php');
require_once('template-parts/9.php');
require_once('template-parts/10.php');
and....
```

**And additional question:**

What solution do you suggest to manage unwanted error messages or warnings in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, your unwanted messages are notices, not errors. They'll probably vanish if you turn off WP_DEBUG. They may, or may not, come from a php version compatibility problem (you didn't tell us what version of php you use). If you turn on both WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG you may (or may not) see full function tracebacks in your `.../wp-content/debug.log` file. That might help you track them down.

Second, `.../wp-includes/functions.php` is not the same file as your theme's functions file. It's a core WordPress file. The offending function in this case is [absint()](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/bea4307daa21a3f97d159898b0ac676332e0e7de/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L5351C1-L5361C2). It looks like some code somewhere tries to convert an error object into a positive integer. That's wierd. But this sort of confusion is fairly common in WordPress code. The other error is similar.

Tracking down the source of the problems will require the tracebacks.